# MySQL query to get all friends of a user including the last sent message between them

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have 3 tables:

os_users (username, user_id),
os_friends (user_id, target_id, lastaction, time),
os_messages (user_id, target_id, message, time).

I now want to get all the "friends" of a user including the last 1 message that was written between both of them.

This query is working fine to get all friends and their usernames, ordered by lastaction between them (24 is for test purposes, its my user_id):

```sql
SELECT os_friends.*, os_users.username, os_users.user_id AS friend_id 
FROM os_friends 
LEFT JOIN os_users ON os_friends.user_id = os_users.user_id OR os_friends.target_id = os_users.user_id

WHERE os_users.user_id != 24 AND (os_friends.user_id = 24 OR os_friends.target_id = 24) 
ORDER BY os_friends.lastaction DESC
```

I would like to get the last message (don't matter who of the 2 people sent it) of that "friendship" too in the results, best would be "AS lastmessage".

Hope you can help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that (user_id, target_id, time) is unique in os_messages table

```
Select * from os_users osu 
left join os_friends osf on osu.user_id = osf.user_id
left join os_messages osm on osm.user_id = osf.user_id and osm.target_id = osf.target_id
where not exists (
  Select * from os_messages osm1 where osm1.user_id = osm.user_id and osm1.target_id = osm.target_id and osm1.time > osm.time
)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply! user_id is unique in os_users. user_id and target_id are the user_id of different users from the os_users table. user_id and target_id are not unique in os_messages, as they can send as much messages as they want to each other. What I need to know now is: how to get the most recent message between them, don't matter who sent it.